# Problema Conectar BD Oracle en Java

Tags: java

No he podido lograr conectarme a una `BD` de **Oracle**, me indica que no reconoce el `SID` el listener, agradecería un montón si me pudieran orientar, mi código es el siguiente :

```
import java.sql.Connection;
Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            DriverManager.registerDriver (new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
            ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@Nombre Maquina o IP :1521:SID", "usr", "pwd");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el SID se lo diste a la BBDD de datos al crearla, es el nombre de la base de datos.

Este es un ejemplo para conectarte a traves del localhost:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class OracleConnection {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String usuario = "nombre_usuario";
        String password = "secreta";

        String host = "localhost"; // tambien puede ser una ip
        String puerto = "1521";
        String sid = "prueba";

        String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";

        String urljdbc = "jdbc:oracle:thin:" + usuario + "/" + password + "@" + host + ":" + puerto + ":" + sid;

        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(urljdbc);

            // Ya tenemos el objeto connection creado

            ResultSet result = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT 'hola mundo' FROM DUAL");
            result.next();
            System.out.println(result.getString(1));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Aunque la manera correcta es conectarte a traves de jdbc, es decir un pool de conexiones.
Entra en GlassFish, crea un pool de conexiones y el recurso.

En tu proyecto web, en el archivo web.xml, tienes que agregar esto:

```
<listener>
    <description>ServletContextListener</description>
    <listener-class>Listener.Oyente</listener-class>
</listener>
<resource-ref>
    <description>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl</description>
    <res-ref-name>ds</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

Crea un archivo glassfish-resources.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/oracle" pool-name="ORCL">
        <description/>
    </jdbc-resource>
    <jdbc-connection-pool 
        allow-non-component-callers="false" 
        associate-with-thread="false" 
        connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" 
        connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" 
        connection-leak-reclaim="false" 
        connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" 
        connection-validation-method="auto-commit" 
        datasource-classname="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" 
        fail-all-connections="false" 
        idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" 
        is-connection-validation-required="false" 
        is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" 
        lazy-connection-association="false" 
        lazy-connection-enlistment="false" 
        match-connections="false" 
        max-connection-usage-count="0" 
        max-pool-size="32" 
        max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" 
        name="ORCL" 
        non-transactional-connections="false" 
        ping="false" 
        pool-resize-quantity="2" 
        pooling="true" 
        res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        statement-cache-size="0" 
        statement-leak-reclaim="false" 
        statement-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" 
        statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" 
        steady-pool-size="8" 
        validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" 
        wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl"/>
        <property name="User" value="NOMBRE_USUARIO"/>
        <property name="Password" value="PASSWORD"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
</resources>
```

Crea una clase Modelo:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class Modelo {

    private DataSource ds;

    public Modelo(DataSource ds) {
        this.ds = ds;
    }

    public boolean existeUsuario(String USUARIO, String CONTRASENA) {
        Connection con = null;
        boolean resultado = true;

        try {
            con = ds.getConnection();
            resultado = false;
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE USUARIO=? AND CONTRASENA=?");
            ps.setString(1, USUARIO);
            ps.setString(2, CONTRASENA);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            rs.next();
            if (rs.getString(1).length() > 0 && rs.getString(2).length() > 0) {
                resultado = true;
            } else {
                resultado = false;
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            resultado = false;
        } finally {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Modelo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        return resultado;
    }
}
```

Por ultimo crea un Listener:

```
import Modelo.Modelo;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class Oyente implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        try {

            Context ctx = new InitialContext();
            DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/oracle");
            Modelo m = new Modelo(ds);
            sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("modelo", m);
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Oyente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    }

}
```